# visual-line-mode-hook not runnng on mode exit

Tags: hooks, visual-line-mode

I would like to have whitespace-newline-mode enabled every time visual-line-mode is enabled, and disabled correspondingly.

The documentation on "visual-line-mode-hook" says "Hook run after entering or leaving `visual-line-mode'."

I put this in my .emacs :

(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook #'whitespace-newline-mode)

When I go into visual-line-mode, I can see the newlines as desired.  However, when I go out of visual-line-mode, the newlines are still there, and I have to manually run whitespace-newline-mode to disable it.

Is the visual-line-mode-hook documentation just *wrong*, or am I missing
something fundamental about add-hook here?

(As an aside: how do I configure the color of the newline characters
that are displayed when I run whitespace-newline-mode?)

Comment: Welcome to emacs.SE! Please consider moving the second question in a separate post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc string of `whitespace-newline-mode` (`C-h f whitespace-newline-mode`) 'includes:

> (whitespace-newline-mode &optional ARG)
>
> Toggle newline visualization (Whitespace Newline mode).
>   With a prefix argument ARG, enable Whitespace Newline mode if ARG
>   is positive, and disable it otherwise.
>
> If called from Lisp, also enables the mode if ARG is omitted or nil,
>   and toggles it if ARG is ‘toggle’.

As you see, the behavior when executed from lisp code is not the same as when executed interactively. So, assuming `whitespace-newline-mode` is disabled by default, you could use:

```el
(add-hook 'visual-line-mode-hook (lambda () (whitespace-newline-mode 'toggle)))
```

Comment: d'oh!  It didn't occur to me to check the docstring on whitespace-newline-mode.  That should have been the obvious thing to do.

Thanks for the tip!